# how to convert string array of objects to array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, converters

I have an array that I want to convert but I have no idea how to do it

how can i convert this array

```
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];
```

in this array

```
const b = [{'/run':true}, {'/sleep':false}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using map and a regular expression:

```js
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];
const b = a.map(s => {
  const [_,k,v] = s.match(/\{(.+):(.+)}/);
  return {[k]: JSON.parse(v)};
});
console.log(b);
```

Or other way is to run a sting replacement and JSON.parse

```js
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];
const b = JSON.parse("[" + a.toString().replace(/\{([^:]+)/g, '{"$1"') + "]");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought of doing `JSON.parse` on the entire entry after removing `' { } ` characters from each entry. But that didn't work. This is the best solution for any potential side-cases and for nested structures. +1

Comment: It would not work because it would not be valid JSON from the lack of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Created this simple function to do exactly that

```js
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];

// desired output
const b = [{ run: true }, { sleep: false }];

const c = a.map(item => {
    const key = item.match(/\w+/)[0];
    const value = item.match(/true|false/)[0];
    return { [key]: value === 'true' };
});

console.log(c);
```

Comment: This is a very non-generic answer, wouldn't recommend this for anything except the example output

Comment: Completely agree with joel. It should only be used to find objects in a string when they aren't properly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];

const c = a.map(item => {
  return {
    ['/' + item.split(':')[1].split('{')[0]]: item.split(':')[1].split('}')[0]
  };
});

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ['{/run:true}', '{/sleep:false}'];

const output = a.map(item => {
    const normalize = item.replaceAll("{", "").replaceAll("}", "")
    const splitedStr = normalize.split(':');
    const key = splitedStr[0];
    const value = splitedStr[1];
    return {[key]: value}
})

console.log(output)
```